# ODP.NET: AccessViolationException when trying to open connection

Tags: access-violation, odp.net

I am trying to learn ODP.NET, and have built a simple example based on [Oracle's Getting Started example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/GettingStartedNETVersion/GettingStartedNETVersion.htm). However, whenever my code hits the conn.Open() statement, it immediately crashes with an AccessViolationException. I am on a 64-bit OS, but running 32-bit versions of the Oracle 11g Client and ODAC. My code is identical to Oracle's example, other than it connecting to a different test database.

Is there something simple I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what was wrong, but I fixed it by manually removing Oracle using the guide [here](http://halimdba.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-manually-remove-oracle-server.html) and reinstalling Oracle client and the ODAC client, and putting ODAC in a separate install directory. My best guess is that I had some residual problems in the registry from an older version of the Oracle client.